# apt-get update not working on Ubuntu 22.04 (security errors and 404 not found)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.04, update-manager

For some reason, when I type `sudo apt-get update` it doesn't work. I tried:

- Changing my "Download from" server in Software & Updates
- Checking my internet connection
- Removing some of the repos from "Other software" in Software & Updates

I'm getting the following error:

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Err:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_17.x impish InRelease
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Hit:8 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:10 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Hirsute is end-of-live, this is way Ubuntu removed the repo from the servers ... remove the hirsute references from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, if you are really on 22.04

Comment: Thank you that worked! I have unselected everything containing Hirsute from the Software & Update but this wasn't enough. I had to remove them from the sources.list.